# Invalid date on JavaScript on .Net Core project

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm having the next issue:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.EndDate" id="dateEnd" />
```

in the hidden input, I have a Date value from a Model this value is 2019/12/31

So I'm trying to use it in JavaScript for some logic in the webpage, here is how I catch it:

```
const endDate = new Date(document.querySelector("#dateEnd").value);
```

When I do this and do a "console.log", the console shows me "Invalid Date".

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: What does `console.log(document.querySelector("#dateEnd").value)` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering the value of a .NET `DateTime` to the hidden field without any formatting. The output will be `31/12/2019 00:00:00`, not the `31/12/2019` that you posted. You can check this by [using the browser developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).  JavaScript is unable to convert that value to a date.

Ideally, when working with dates in HTML, you should use an [ISO 8601 format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats) to prevent this kind of issue. You can use a [DateTime format string](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/23/date-formatting-in-c) to do this:

`<input type="hidden" value="@Model.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" id="dateEnd" />`